# Beautifulsoup extract inside <br> tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have html code like this

```
<td><b>Total : 32</b><br/>Mango : 12<br/>Banana : 4<br/>Grape : 16<br/>Watermelon : 0 </td>
```

How can i extract it to variable like this?

```
Total : 32
Mango : 12
Banana : 4
Grape : 16
Watermelon : 0
```

Just get the number, the name as variable

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
a = '<td><b>Total : 32</b><br/>Mango : 12<br/>Banana : 4<br/>Grape : 16<br/>Watermelon : 0 </td>'
for i in a.strings:
    print(i)
```

Remember, a is not a string but a `<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>`. this gives the output:

```
Total : 32
Mango : 12
Banana : 4
Grape : 16
Watermelon : 0
```

This can be stored as a dictionary:

```
dc = {}
for i in a.strings:
    dc[i.split()[0]] = int(i.split()[-1])
```

this gives:

```
{'Total': 32, 'Mango': 12, 'Banana': 4, 'Grape': 16, 'Watermelon': 0}
```

---

Now if you are sure that you need variables like Total which has the value 32, try (not recommended method):

```
for i in a.strings:
    exec(f'{i.split()[0]} = int(i.split()[-1])')
```

Now call them:

```
>>>Total
32
>>>Mango
12
```

Comment: Why is this (or any of these solutions) downvoted!?

Comment: i mean just get the number. the text is variable name

Comment: @DwiCahya try now. added a bit

Answer (score 2):

You can also use FOP approach (assuming that you've already soup created as `soup`:

```py
map(lambda br: print(br.text), soup.find_all('br'))
```